# Vue this.watch() function parameters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to watch a variable in Vue inside a Vuex store module.

What I've got is the following, using this.watch(), and I'm assuming that the parameters are meant to be `this.watch(oldValue, newValue)`, following the convention of using watchers in a Vue module.

```
this.watch(
      () => myVariableToWatch, () => {
        console.log('myVariableToWatch has changed');
      });
```

Is this the best way of doing this?

I looked through the Vue docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: You can't use watch inside the Vuex store. Where exactly do you use this snippet of code. would' need more Information:

- Where is this code, maybe what is around?
- What exactly do you want to watch?
- what do you want to achive?

Comment: See https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch . You need to use Vuex API, not Vue. Can also be `subscribe`. "Is this the best way of doing this?" -  it's unknown what you try to do. Generally you rarely ever need this for Vuex. Usually you're aware where specific state modifications are made because this is done in actions/mutations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Vue instance prefixed with `$` and used as follows :

```
this.$watch(myVar,(newVal,oldVal)=>{
    

})
```